# how to solve Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, localhost, mysql-event

Any idea on the solution?

```
SQL query:


    SET GLOBAL event_scheduler="ON"
    MySQL said: Documentation

    #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

I am trying to   SET GLOBAL event_scheduler="ON"

Comment: it seems straight forward, you logt in user hqasn't the necessary privileges, see here for more informtion how to get it https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-add-super-privileges-to-mysql-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your user doesn't have the necessary MySQL permissions to enable the event scheduler. You'll have to ask your administrator or hosting provider to either enable the scheduler for the server themselves or give you the SUPER privilege (which is [basically permissions to manage administration](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) tasks and advanced configuration of the server).

There's nothing extra you can do or nothing wrong with phpMyAdmin, it's simply that your administrator hasn't given you the proper privileges to do that.